# How we get product rating via product id in magento2?

Tags: magento2, review

I am tired to get rating by product id in magento2 ?
here is my code for get reviews rating .

```
 protected $reviewModel;  
public function __construct(

\Magento\Review\Model\Review $reviewModel,

    array $data = []
)
{

    $this->reviewModel = $reviewModel;

}

  public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
{
    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $this->reviewModel->appendSummary($products);
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $products;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to avail product rating through product ID in Magento 2

```
<?php 
    $_productid = 12;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $RatingOb = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Rating')->getEntitySummary($_productid);   
    $ratings = $RatingOb->getSum()/$RatingOb->getCount(); 
?>


<div class="product-reviews-summary">
    <div class="rating-summary">
        <span class="label"><span>Rating:</span></span>
        <div class="rating-result">
            <span style="width:<?php echo $ratings; ?>%"><span><span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $ratings; ?></span>% of <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span></span></span>
        </div>
        <?php echo '('.$RatingOb->getCount().')'; ?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

You have to manage using css as per display rating requirement.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to retrieve review form for a product on custom phtml?

Answer (score 2):

**How we get product rating via product id in magento2?**

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getRatingSummary()
{
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my reputation is less than 50 so I couldn't reply to your comment. 
below is the code to get the review from the product

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); //Fetch product from model or from same file
            //Description
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $_product->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();

$reviewDetails = $collection->getData();
foreach ($reviewDetails as $key => $review) {
                    print_r($review);
                    ?>
                        <div class="review-block">
                            <dt><span>By  <?php echo $review['nickname']; ?></span></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <p>Rating<?php echo $review['review_id']; ?></p>
                                <p><?php echo $review['detail']; ?></p>
                                <small class="date">(Posted on <?php echo $review['created_at'] ?>)</small>
                            </dd>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    <?php
                }
```