# How to call getReviewsCollection() function from Magento\Review\Block\Product\View?

Tags: magento2

At the bottom of the page I have created a custom module in that I want to call `getReviewsCollection()` function to display information of reviews?

Can anyone please help me?

Bottom of the page custom module is displayed.

I have used https://github.com/MauroNigrele/magento2-test-modules/tree/master/Test/Catalog/view/frontend to create custom module.

**Test/Review/registration.php**

```
 <?php
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Test_Review',
      __DIR__
 );
```

**Test/Review/etc/module.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Test_Review" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_Review"/>
    </sequence>
 </module>
 </config>
```

**Test/Review/Block/Product/View/Extra.php**

```
  <?php
 namespace Test\Review\Block\Product\View;
 use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
 class Extra extends AbstractProduct
 {

 }
```

**Test/Review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/extra.phtml**

```
 <?php /* @var $block \Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra */?>
 <?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
 <h3><?php echo 'My Product Name Is: ' . $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
```

**Test/Review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
    <block class="Test\Review\Block\Product\View\Extra"
        name="product.view.extra"
        template="Test_Review::product/view/extra.phtml"
        after="-">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: please show your full code.

Comment: @Rakesh please see my full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom module you need to use object of `\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection`   which will give you collection of reviews.

In your Block class `Extra` , inject `\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection` in `__construct()` and use it.

Example:

```
public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection $reviewCollection
..
) {
..
$this->reviewCollection = $reviewCollection;
..
}
public function getReviewCollection()
{
    return $this->reviewCollection;
}
```

and call this function `getReviewCollection()` in your template file using `$block->getReviewCollection()`.

Example:

```
$reviews = $block->getReviewCollection();
foreach ($reviews as $review) {
    echo $review->getReviewId();
}
```

Above program is used to return all reviews and not related to a particular product. If you want to get reviews for a particular product you need to follow [How we get product rating via product id in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116918/how-we-get-product-rating-via-product-id-in-magento2)